# Duplicates Reduction

Tags: java

If I have a string say "Hello" n I wants to remove the duplicates from the string. If I uses StringBuilder to remove the character at index 2 "l" , will the next "l" takes position of the previous one after deleting it??

Comment: Did you try it? Trying it probably would have taken less time than it took to ask the question.

Comment: You have be more specific. Share what you did. Code sample.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get issue simple. We don't need to delete duplicate character. We just remove the charachter at index 2. The string is "abcde".

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcde");
char one = sb.charAt(2); // comment1, we know it's 'c'
sb = sb.deleteCharAt(2); // comment2, let's delete 'c'. What would "abcde" be?
// It's so ugly to be "ab de", so designer makes it be "abde"
char two = sb.charAt(2); // comment3, now you will know the result ^v^
```

For comment2, how does it make "abcde" to "abde"? Let's look into source of StringBuilder. StringBuilder is a subClass of AbstractStringBuilder. And deleteCharAt(int index) is implemented in AbstractStringBuilder.

```
public AbstractStringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
    count--;
    return this;
}
```

Let's omite index validation. What does `System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);` do? You can find it's doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
                             int srcPos,
                             Object dest,
                             int destPos,
                             int length)
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array (which is "abcde"), beginning at the
>   specified position (`index+1`, which is 3), to the specified position (`index`, which is 2) of the destination
>   array (which is "abcde" too). A subsequence of array components are copied from the source
>   array referenced by `src` to the destination array referenced by `dest` (`src` and `dest` are the same here, "abcde").
>   The number of components copied is equal to the `length` argument (`length` here is 5-2-1, it's 2. So it will copy 2 chars). The
>   components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos+length-1` in the source
>   array are copied into positions `destPos` through `destPos+length-1` (`srcPos` here is 2+1, it's 3. `srcPos+length-1` is 3+2-1, it's 4),
>   respectively, of the destination array.

So `System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);` means copy 2 chars from index 3, to override index 2, override from index 2 to 3. Copy 'de' to override 'cd'. So after `System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);`, makes `sb.value` to be "abdee"(Delete 'l' already.). then count--, means "abdee" remove last char, so it becomes "abde".

`will the next "l" takes position of the previous one after deleting it?` Yes, it will.

See? Coding is not so hard and not so mystic. And the direct way is code yourself and run it.